# Display Sale Price Before Regular Price (WooCommerce)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, price

I'd like to display the sale price of a product before the regular (discounted) price. I know this has something to do with `get_price_html`. By default, this outputs something like:

```
<del>regular price</del>
<ins>sale price</ins>
```

I want to change the output so it looks like this (basically, the two prices are shown in a different order):

```
<ins>sale price</ins>
<del>regular price</del>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Check this http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/83367/woocommerce-how-to-edit-the-get-price-html

Comment: And http://inikweb.com/how-to-change-get_price_html-in-woocommerce/

Comment: @Moak, I did check those links but haven't figured out how they would help me in this case. None of them mentions anything about changing the order of the two elements.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Yes you have to alter `get_price_html` method which can be done by
>   using following hook's:
>
> 1. For Simple Product: [`woocommerce_get_price_html`](http://hookr.io/filters/woocommerce_get_price_html/) hook.
> 2. For Variable Product: [`woocommerce_variation_sale_price_html`](http://hookr.io/filters/woocommerce_variation_sale_price_html/) & [`woocommerce_variation_price_html`](http://hookr.io/filters/woocommerce_variation_price_html/)
> 3. For Variable Product Min Max Price: [`woocommerce_variable_sale_price_html`](http://hookr.io/filters/woocommerce_variable_sale_price_html/) &
>      [`woocommerce_variable_price_html`](http://hookr.io/filters/woocommerce_variable_price_html/)

#### UPDATED *16th Feb 2018*

Here is the code:

**For WooCommerce version `2.6.x` or below**

```
if (!function_exists('my_commonPriceHtml')) {

    function my_commonPriceHtml($price_amt, $regular_price, $sale_price) {
        $html_price = '<p class="price">';
        //if product is in sale
        if (($price_amt == $sale_price) && ($sale_price != 0)) {
            $html_price .= '<ins>' . woocommerce_price($sale_price) . '</ins>';
            $html_price .= '<del>' . woocommerce_price($regular_price) . '</del>';
        }
        //in sale but free
        else if (($price_amt == $sale_price) && ($sale_price == 0)) {
            $html_price .= '<ins>Free!</ins>';
            $html_price .= '<del>' . woocommerce_price($regular_price) . '</del>';
        }
        //not is sale
        else if (($price_amt == $regular_price) && ($regular_price != 0)) {
            $html_price .= '<ins>' . woocommerce_price($regular_price) . '</ins>';
        }
        //for free product
        else if (($price_amt == $regular_price) && ($regular_price == 0)) {
            $html_price .= '<ins>Free!</ins>';
        }
        $html_price .= '</p>';
        return $html_price;
    }

}

add_filter('woocommerce_get_price_html', 'my_simple_product_price_html', 100, 2);

function my_simple_product_price_html($price, $product) {
    if ($product->is_type('simple')) {
        $regular_price = $product->regular_price;
        $sale_price = $product->sale_price;
        $price_amt = $product->price;
        return my_commonPriceHtml($price_amt, $regular_price, $sale_price);
    } else {
        return $price;
    }
}

add_filter('woocommerce_variation_sale_price_html', 'my_variable_product_price_html', 10, 2);
add_filter('woocommerce_variation_price_html', 'my_variable_product_price_html', 10, 2);

function my_variable_product_price_html($price, $variation) {
    $variation_id = $variation->variation_id;
    //creating the product object
    $variable_product = new WC_Product($variation_id);

    $regular_price = $variable_product->regular_price;
    $sale_price = $variable_product->sale_price;
    $price_amt = $variable_product->price;

    return my_commonPriceHtml($price_amt, $regular_price, $sale_price);
}

add_filter('woocommerce_variable_sale_price_html', 'my_variable_product_minmax_price_html', 10, 2);
add_filter('woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'my_variable_product_minmax_price_html', 10, 2);

function my_variable_product_minmax_price_html($price, $product) {
    $variation_min_price = $product->get_variation_price('min', true);
    $variation_max_price = $product->get_variation_price('max', true);
    $variation_min_regular_price = $product->get_variation_regular_price('min', true);
    $variation_max_regular_price = $product->get_variation_regular_price('max', true);

    if (($variation_min_price == $variation_min_regular_price) && ($variation_max_price == $variation_max_regular_price)) {
        $html_min_max_price = $price;
    } else {
        $html_price = '<p class="price">';
        $html_price .= '<ins>' . woocommerce_price($variation_min_price) . '-' . woocommerce_price($variation_max_price) . '</ins>';
        $html_price .= '<del>' . woocommerce_price($variation_min_regular_price) . '-' . woocommerce_price($variation_max_regular_price) . '</del>';
        $html_min_max_price = $html_price;
    }

    return $html_min_max_price;
}
```

**For WooCommerce version `3.0` or above**

```
if (!function_exists('my_commonPriceHtml')) {

    function my_commonPriceHtml($price_amt, $regular_price, $sale_price) {
        $html_price = '<p class="price">';
        //if product is in sale
        if (($price_amt == $sale_price) && ($sale_price != 0)) {
            $html_price .= '<ins>' . wc_price($sale_price) . '</ins>';
            $html_price .= '<del>' . wc_price($regular_price) . '</del>';
        }
        //in sale but free
        else if (($price_amt == $sale_price) && ($sale_price == 0)) {
            $html_price .= '<ins>Free!</ins>';
            $html_price .= '<del>' . wc_price($regular_price) . '</del>';
        }
        //not is sale
        else if (($price_amt == $regular_price) && ($regular_price != 0)) {
            $html_price .= '<ins>' . wc_price($regular_price) . '</ins>';
        }
        //for free product
        else if (($price_amt == $regular_price) && ($regular_price == 0)) {
            $html_price .= '<ins>Free!</ins>';
        }
        $html_price .= '</p>';
        return $html_price;
    }

}

add_filter('woocommerce_get_price_html', 'my_simple_product_price_html', 100, 2);

function my_simple_product_price_html($price, $product) {
    if ($product->is_type('simple')) {
        $regular_price = $product->get_regular_price();
        $sale_price = $product->get_sale_price();
        $price_amt = $product->get_price();
        return my_commonPriceHtml($price_amt, $regular_price, $sale_price);
    } else {
        return $price;
    }
}

add_filter('woocommerce_variation_sale_price_html', 'my_variable_product_price_html', 10, 2);
add_filter('woocommerce_variation_price_html', 'my_variable_product_price_html', 10, 2);

function my_variable_product_price_html($price, $variation) {
    $variation_id = $variation->variation_id;
    //creating the product object
    $variable_product = new WC_Product($variation_id);

    $regular_price = $variable_product->get_regular_price();
    $sale_price = $variable_product->get_sale_price();
    $price_amt = $variable_product->get_price();

    return my_commonPriceHtml($price_amt, $regular_price, $sale_price);
}

add_filter('woocommerce_variable_sale_price_html', 'my_variable_product_minmax_price_html', 10, 2);
add_filter('woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'my_variable_product_minmax_price_html', 10, 2);

function my_variable_product_minmax_price_html($price, $product) {
    $variation_min_price = $product->get_variation_price('min', true);
    $variation_max_price = $product->get_variation_price('max', true);
    $variation_min_regular_price = $product->get_variation_regular_price('min', true);
    $variation_max_regular_price = $product->get_variation_regular_price('max', true);

    if (($variation_min_price == $variation_min_regular_price) && ($variation_max_price == $variation_max_regular_price)) {
        $html_min_max_price = $price;
    } else {
        $html_price = '<p class="price">';
        $html_price .= '<ins>' . wc_price($variation_min_price) . '-' . wc_price($variation_max_price) . '</ins>';
        $html_price .= '<del>' . wc_price($variation_min_regular_price) . '-' . wc_price($variation_max_regular_price) . '</del>';
        $html_min_max_price = $html_price;
    }

    return $html_min_max_price;
}
```

*Code goes in [`functions.php`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Functions_File_Explained) file of your active child theme (or theme). Or also in any plugin php files.*
**Code is tested and works.**

Hope this helps!

Comment: Something isn't right as now both prices have disappeared. Instead, I can only see "Free!". What might be causing this? Thanks!

Comment: Also, the order of the two prices hasn't changes (del is still before ins).

Comment: @LucreziavanNecker: can you tell me what you have written in `Regular price` and `Sale price` field and it is simple product or variable product?

Comment: the products are all variable products. Regular price is £56 and sale price is £23.

Comment: ok, thanks, I have tested for simple product, will test and update my answer

Comment: @LucreziavanNecker: I have updated my answer and it is working with different price combination and simple and variable product type, please have a look.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong because I copied and pasted the entire code you provided above in my functions.php file and it is not working. `<del></del>` still shows up before `<ins></ins>` Do I need to change any of the hooks from above? Or is the code supposed to be working as is now, without any changes/edits?

Comment: UPDATE: It seems to be working, but now both prices appear twice. See here:  [link](http://i65.tinypic.com/1lout.png)

Comment: Last update: It's working well now. I have simply replaced `$html_price .= '<ins>' . woocommerce_price($variation_min_price) . '-' . woocommerce_price($variation_max_price) . '</ins>';
        $html_price .= '<del>' . woocommerce_price($variation_min_regular_price) . '-' . woocommerce_price($variation_max_regular_price) . '</del>';` with `$html_price .= '<ins>' . woocommerce_price($variation_min_price) . '</ins>';
        $html_price .= '<del>' . woocommerce_price($variation_min_regular_price) . '</del>';` and now I have `<ins></ins>` before `<del></del>`. It is showing up just once.

Comment: @LucreziavanNecker: Ok.

Comment: `woocommerce_price` is now deprecated (Woocommerce 3.0) you should use `wc_price` instead.

Comment: @retober: thanks a lot, when I written this answer WooCommerce 3.0 was't released. I'll updated my answer.

Comment: @Raunak Gupta: this does not work if the woocommerce tax settings are set to "No, I will enter prices exclusive of tax".  The price displays excluding the taxes but it should show with the taxes.