# Adding custom text labels to the prices when products are on sale

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, price

On WooCommerce product single pages, if a product owns a sales price, the normal price is crossed out and behind it, the sale price is highlighted.

My question: 
How can I add a label like **`"Old Price: XX Dollar"`** and **`"New Price: XX Dollar"`** instead of only the crossed out and the new price (sale price)?

Comment: may be this answer can help you. http://stackoverflow.com/a/41410818/5019802. and do you have only simple product?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Update 2 (for simple and variable products + solved the bug on same variations prices)**

when products are on sale, you can add custom labels just as you want using a custom function hooked in **`woocommerce_sale_price_html`** and **`woocommerce_variation_sale_price_html`** filters hooks (for simple and variables products.

For the min / max prices in variables products, we need a different function hooked in **`woocommerce_variation_sale_price_html`** filter hook.

Here is that code:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_variation_sale_price_html','sale_prices_custom_labels', 10, 2 );
add_filter('woocommerce_sale_price_html','sale_prices_custom_labels', 10, 2 );
function sale_prices_custom_labels( $price, $product ){
    if (isset($product->sale_price)) {
        $price = '<del class="strike">' . __('Old Price: ', 'woocommerce' ) . woocommerce_price( $product->regular_price ). '</del>
        <ins class="highlight">' . __('New Price: ', 'woocommerce' ) . woocommerce_price( $product->sale_price ) . '</ins>';
    }
    else
    {
        $price = '<ins class="highlight">'.woocommerce_price( $product->regular_price ).'</ins>';
    }
    return $price;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_variable_sale_price_html', 'sale_prices_custom_labels_min_max', 20, 2);
function sale_prices_custom_labels_min_max( $price, $product) {

    $variation_min_reg_price = $product->get_variation_regular_price('min', true);
    $variation_max_reg_price = $product->get_variation_regular_price('max', true);
    $variation_min_sale_price = $product->get_variation_sale_price('min', true);
    $variation_max_sale_price = $product->get_variation_sale_price('max', true);

    if ( $variation_min_reg_price != $variation_min_sale_price || $variation_max_reg_price != $variation_max_sale_price )
    {
        if($variation_min_reg_price == $variation_max_reg_price && $variation_min_sale_price == $variation_max_sale_price ){
            $price = '<del class="strike">' . __('Old Price: ', 'woocommerce' ) . woocommerce_price($variation_max_reg_price) . '</del>
            <ins class="highlight">' . __('New Price: ', 'woocommerce' ) . woocommerce_price($variation_max_sale_price) . '</ins>';
        }
        elseif($variation_min_reg_price != $variation_max_reg_price && $variation_min_sale_price == $variation_max_sale_price )
        {
            $price = '<del class="strike">' . __('Old Price: ', 'woocommerce' ) . woocommerce_price($variation_min_reg_price) . '-' . woocommerce_price($variation_max_reg_price) . '</del>
            <ins class="highlight">' . __('New Price: ', 'woocommerce' ) . woocommerce_price($variation_max_sale_price) . '</ins>';
        }
        elseif($variation_min_reg_price == $variation_max_reg_price && $variation_min_sale_price != $variation_max_sale_price )
        {
            $price = '<del class="strike">' . __('Old Price: ', 'woocommerce' ) . woocommerce_price($variation_max_reg_price) . '</del>
            <ins class="highlight">' . __('New Price: ', 'woocommerce' ) . woocommerce_price($variation_min_sale_price) . '-' . woocommerce_price($variation_max_sale_price) . '</ins>';
        }
        else
        {
        $price = '<del class="strike">' . __('Old Price: ', 'woocommerce' ) . woocommerce_price($variation_min_reg_price) . '-' . woocommerce_price($variation_max_reg_price) . '</del>
        <ins class="highlight">' . __('New Price: ', 'woocommerce' ) . woocommerce_price($variation_min_sale_price) . '-' . woocommerce_price($variation_max_sale_price) . '</ins>';
        }
    }
    return $price;
}
```

> You can also replace the normal **`<ins>`** and **`<del>`** html tags by something else and change or add some classes too (if is more convenient for you). **At this point everithing is possible.**

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested and works.

---

Related answers: [Conditional custom output around products sale price and regular price](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37606772/conditional-custom-output-around-products-sale-price-and-regular-price/37607104#37607104)

Comment: Works really well! But in one case, it doesn't work... if a product is on sale and is also available in product variations (for example in different colors) this doesn't work. Have you any solution for this?

Comment: @user6573193 Updated my answer with functional tested and working code for both product types (simple and variable products)

Comment: Thank you! I upvoted the answer! I found a little bug... if a product variation costs the same in each variation, the label is „New price: 130-130 Dollar“ - have you any solution for this?

Comment: @user6573193 I have solved this bug and updated my code…

Answer (score 0):

In admin side you need to define your sale price and actual price so it will automatically reflect in front side as your old price and new price alternatively.

Also you need to do some code for this.

Comment: This is correct, I know... but I want a label around the two prices that says „Old Price: 100 Dollar“ - „New Price: 90 Dollar“
Instead of „-100 Dollar- 90 Dollar“

Comment: you need to add code before old price and new price :)

Comment: I know... this is the reason why I ask here... how must the filter for this looks like? I do not want to write in the templates in this case.