# Adding custom text labels to the product prices depending on their type

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, price

I have one little problem that I can't solve yet. 
I have this [WooCommerce web site](http://www.wholesaleunderwear.co/product/men-s-crew-sport-sock-w-logo/) with variable products, and currently prices are shown in this way:

$5.50 per dozen – $100.00 per dozen

I use this CSS rule that adds "per dozen" after every price, but that dont make sense in the current scenario.

```
.price .amount:after {
content: " per dozen";
}
```

I would like to show the prices on this variable products this way:

$5.50 **per dozen** – $100.00 **per case (quantity number)**

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What happens and what would you like to happen?

Comment: Do you checked the link in my question? Currently show 




$5.50 per dozen –$100.00 per dozen
and want to show like 

$5.50 per dozen –$100.00 per case

Understand, price for piece, and bulk price.

Comment: I can't check external links. You need to provide a [mcve]

Comment: See this image: http://i.imgur.com/KKrtpvj.png?1 You see that currently show $5.50 per dozen –$100.00 per dozen, and i want only to show $5.50 per dozen –$100.00 per case. Thats all.

Comment: change the CSS class, or make a new one and add it only there.

Comment: Not help me that. I allready checked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you are going to be able to add custom labels just as you want using a custom function hooked in **`woocommerce_price_html`** and **`woocommerce_variation_price_html`** filters hooks (for simple and variables products.

For the min / max prices in variables products, we need a separated function hooked in **`woocommerce_variation_sale_price_html`** filter hook.

> **Update:** AS my code will now will handle also " per dozen"  on single products too, **you have to remove your custom CSS rule `.price .amount:after { content: " per dozen";}`**.

**This will avoid to have a repetitive "per dozen" everywhere.**

> **But it's not possible to set a different label on the live price based on the selected attributes values.** For that the only way is using **Javascript/jQuery**, as this is a live event on client side...

**Update2**
Here is that working  and tested code *(see the screenshots at the end)*:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_variation_price_html','prices_custom_labels', 10, 2 );
add_filter('woocommerce_price_html','prices_custom_labels', 10, 2 );
function prices_custom_labels( $price, $product ){

    // Custom label name
    $per_dozen = ' '. __('per dozen', 'woocommerce' );

    // Set HERE your "quantity" attribute slug
    $attribute_qty_slug = 'pa_quantity';

    $attribute_qty_slug_key = 'attribute_'.$attribute_qty_slug;
    $append_label = '';

    // 1) Variable products
    if ($product->product_type != 'simple' && $product->variation_id ) {

        // Getting the attribute "quantity" value
        $attribute_qty_is_set = $product->variation_data[$attribute_qty_slug_key];

        // if "quantity" not set we display " per dozen"
        if( ! $attribute_qty_is_set )
            $append_label = $per_dozen;


        // Outputed price + custom label
        $price = '<ins class="highlight">'.woocommerce_price( $product->regular_price ).$append_label.'</ins>';
    }
    // 2) Simple products
    else
    {
        // Here the output price + custom default label
        $price = '<ins class="highlight">'.woocommerce_price( $product->regular_price ).$per_dozen.'</ins>';
    }
    return $price;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'prices_custom_labels_min_max', 20, 2);
function prices_custom_labels_min_max( $price, $product) {

    // Custom label name
    $per_dozen = ' '. __('per dozen', 'woocommerce' );
    $per_case = ' '. __('per case', 'woocommerce' );

    // Set HERE your quantity attribute slug
    $attribute_qty_slug = 'pa_quantity';


    // Getting the min and max variations prices
    $variation_min_reg_price = $product->get_variation_regular_price('min', true);
    $variation_max_reg_price = $product->get_variation_regular_price('max', true);
    $variation_reg_price = $product->get_variation_regular_price();


    if( $variation_min_reg_price == $variation_max_reg_price )
    {
        $price = '<ins class="highlight">'.woocommerce_price($variation_reg_price) . $per_dozen . '</ins>';
    }
    else
    {
        if( !in_array( $attribute_qty_slug, array_keys( $product->get_attributes() ) ) )
        {
            $price = '<ins class="highlight">' . woocommerce_price($variation_min_reg_price) . $per_dozen . ' - ' . woocommerce_price($variation_max_reg_price) . $per_dozen . '</ins>';
        }
        else
        {
            $price = '<ins class="highlight">' . woocommerce_price($variation_min_reg_price) . $per_dozen . ' - ' . woocommerce_price($variation_max_reg_price) . $per_case . '</ins>';
        }
    }
    return $price;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file*.

---

Here is a real screenshot from my test sever:

[image]

This code is tested and really works.

---

Related answers:

- [Adding custom text labels to the prices when products are on sale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42158091/adding-custom-text-labels-to-the-prices-when-products-are-on-sale/42159533#42159533)
- [Adding the discount percentage to variable products on sale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42230027/adding-for-variable-products-on-sale-the-discounted-percentage/42230308#42230308)

Comment: That you so much @loictheaztec. But have issue with your code on my site. Check image:

http://i.imgur.com/Mk3FRZ7.png?1

Comment: @Dora Have you removed your custom related CSS rule?

Comment: Aha, let me remove then my custom CSS rule.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136075/discussion-between-dora-and-loictheaztec).

Comment: your sollution worked but only on single product. When search in show, for ex here: http://www.wholesaleunderwear.co/shop/page/5/

in every product show me price "0 per dozens" . How to fix that, to show single price, if not have set bulk price in product ?

Comment: Someone with tips how to resolve this issue? Answer that was posted before si working but have issue with products that was not have min and max price.

Answer (score 0):

This code resolve one of issue:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_variable_price_html',    'prices_custom_labels_min_max', 20, 2);
function prices_custom_labels_min_max( $price, $product) {

// Set HERE your custom labels names
$per_dozen = ' '. __('per dozen', 'woocommerce' );
$per_case = ' '. __('per case', 'woocommerce' );

// Getting the min and max variations prices
$variation_min_reg_price = $product->get_variation_regular_price('min',   true);
$variation_max_reg_price = $product->get_variation_regular_price('max',   true);

if( $variation_min_reg_price == $variation_max_reg_price ){
    $price = '<ins   class="highlight">'.woocommerce_price($variation_min_reg_price) . $per_dozen .    '</ins>';
}
else
{
    $price = '<ins class="highlight">' .   woocommerce_price($variation_min_reg_price) . $per_dozen . ' - ' .   woocommerce_price($variation_max_reg_price) . $per_case . '</ins>';
}
return $price;
}
```