# Variable product selectors: Getting the live selected values

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

In WooCommerce use the code below to add a custom label after product prices in simple and variables products:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_variation_price_html','prices_custom_labels', 10, 2    );
add_filter('woocommerce_price_html','prices_custom_labels', 10, 2 );
function prices_custom_labels( $price, $product ){

    // Set HERE your custom labels names
    $per_dozen = ' '. __('per dozen', 'woocommerce' );
    $per_case = ' '. __('per case (20 dozens)', 'woocommerce' );


    // 1) Variable products
    if ($product->product_type != 'simple' && $product->variation_id ) {

        // Getting the array of existing attributes values for a variation
        $variation_attribute_value = $product->variation_data;
        // Here we keep only the last value in this array
        $last_variation_attribute_slug_value = ' ' .    end($variation_attribute_value);

        // Finding the word 'case' in the attribute value slug
        $has_case = strstr($last_variation_attribute_slug_value, 'case');

        // Setting the right displayed label depending on attribute value slug
        if( $has_case )
            $attribute_quantity_name_value = $per_case;
        else
            $attribute_quantity_name_value = $per_dozen;

        // Here the output price + custom label
        $price = '<ins class="highlight">'.woocommerce_price( $product-   >regular_price ).$attribute_quantity_name_value.'</ins>';
    }
    // 2) Simple products
    else
    {
        // Here the output price + custom default label
        $price = '<ins class="highlight">'.woocommerce_price( $product-  >regular_price ).$per_dozen.'</ins>';
    }
    return $price;
}
```

But in variable products, I have an issue with the appended custom label in the  live displayed price. The code that I use only display after the live price "per dozen".

I will need to get the selected value on the custom "quantity" selector to add the right label after the price:

- If the selected value is "Dozen" I need to display after live price " per dozen",
- If the selected value is "Case (20 dozens)" I need to display after live price " per case (20 dozens)".

This screenshot is what I have actually for all cases:

[image]

Check this issue on my web site [**specific product page**](http://www.wholesaleunderwear.co/product/men-s-crew-sport-sock-w-logo/)

> So I would need to get the attribute "quantity" selected value to append the right label to the live price.

What can I do to get that working?

Comment: Unable to open the link!

Comment: Just opened without issues.. What error you get? Try again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only way to get this working is to use Javascript / jQuery, but it's complicated as WooCommerce is already running  some Javascript / Ajax code on it.

First, **Is not possible** to detect the selected customer choice on the selectors as WooCommerce remove `"selected"` attribute from `<option>` html tags.

> Once customer have make a complete selection (so choosed one variation from this variable product), **Woocommerce add the corresponding variation ID** value in a **hidden `<imput>` html field** and display the corresponding price.
>
> Our PHP code pass to javascript **an array of the variations IDs** for this variable product, **with the corresponding value of the "quantity" attribute** for each of them.
>
> Then we can use the **"on blur"** javascript event on the **`<select>`** html tags **to get that hidden `variation ID`** value and then **append the price with the right "label"**.

Here is that functional code, that will add a custom label to the live price depending on the customer selection *(so the selected product variation)*:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form', 'custom_get_variations_js' );
function custom_get_variations_js() {
    global $product;

    // Set HERE your "quantity" attribute slug
    $attribute_qty_slug = 'pa_quantity';
    $attribute_qty_slug_key = 'attribute_'.$attribute_qty_slug;

    foreach($product->get_available_variations() as $values){
        $attribute_qty_slug_value = $values['attributes'][$attribute_qty_slug_key];
        $attribute_qty_name_value = get_term_by( 'slug', $attribute_qty_slug_value, $attribute_qty_slug );
        $variations_id_arr[$values['variation_id']] = __(' per ', 'woocommerce' ) . strtolower($attribute_qty_name_value->name);
    }

    ## THE JQUERY SCRIPT ##
    ?>
    <script>
        (function($){
            var $attributes;
            <?php
                // Passing the product variations attributes array to javascript
                $js_array = json_encode($variations_id_arr);
                echo 'var $variationsIdsAttr = '. $js_array ;
            ?>
            $('td.value select').blur(function() {
                var $variationId = $('input[name="variation_id"]').val();
                if (typeof $variationId !== 'undefined' ){
                    for(key in $variationsIdsAttr){
                        if( key == $variationId ){
                            $attributes = $variationsIdsAttr[key];
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if ( typeof $attributes !== 'undefined' ){
                    $('.woocommerce-variation-price .woocommerce-Price-amount.amount').append( $attributes );
                }
            });
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Then we need to change your existing code to avoid displaying a second custom label on this specifics variable products (in the first hooked function):

```
add_filter('woocommerce_variation_price_html','prices_custom_labels', 10, 2 );
add_filter('woocommerce_price_html','prices_custom_labels', 10, 2 );
function prices_custom_labels( $price, $product ){

    // Custom label name
    $per_dozen = ' '. __('per dozen', 'woocommerce' );

    // Set HERE your "quantity" attribute slug
    $attribute_qty_slug = 'pa_quantity';

    $attribute_qty_slug_key = 'attribute_'.$attribute_qty_slug;
    $append_label = '';

    // 1) Variable products
    if ($product->product_type != 'simple' && $product->variation_id ) {

        // Getting the attribute "quantity" value
        $attribute_qty_is_set = $product->variation_data[$attribute_qty_slug_key];
        echo '<pre>'; print_r($product->variation_data[$attribute_qty_slug_key]); echo '</pre>';

        // if "quantity" not set we display " per dozen"
        if( ! $attribute_qty_is_set )
            $append_label = $per_dozen;


        // Outputed price + custom label
        $price = '<ins class="highlight">'.woocommerce_price( $product->regular_price ).$append_label.'</ins>';
    }
    // 2) Simple products
    else
    {
        // Here the output price + custom default label
        $price = '<ins class="highlight">'.woocommerce_price( $product->regular_price ).$per_dozen.'</ins>';
    }
    return $price;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'prices_custom_labels_min_max', 20, 2);
function prices_custom_labels_min_max( $price, $product) {

    // Custom label name
    $per_dozen = ' '. __('per dozen', 'woocommerce' );
    $per_case = ' '. __('per case', 'woocommerce' );

    // Set HERE your quantity attribute slug
    $attribute_qty_slug = 'pa_quantity';


    // Getting the min and max variations prices
    $variation_min_reg_price = $product->get_variation_regular_price('min', true);
    $variation_max_reg_price = $product->get_variation_regular_price('max', true);
    $variation_reg_price = $product->get_variation_regular_price();


    if( $variation_min_reg_price == $variation_max_reg_price )
    {
        $price = '<ins class="highlight">'.woocommerce_price($variation_reg_price) . $per_dozen . '</ins>';
    }
    else
    {
        if( !in_array( $attribute_qty_slug, array_keys( $product->get_attributes() ) ) )
        {
            $price = '<ins class="highlight">' . woocommerce_price($variation_min_reg_price) . $per_dozen . ' - ' . woocommerce_price($variation_max_reg_price) . $per_dozen . '</ins>';
        }
        else
        {
            $price = '<ins class="highlight">' . woocommerce_price($variation_min_reg_price) . $per_dozen . ' - ' . woocommerce_price($variation_max_reg_price) . $per_case . '</ins>';
        }
    }
    // print_r($product->get_attributes());
    return $price;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

---

Related answer:

- [Pass the chosen product variations data into Contact Form 7 enquiry form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42165213/pass-the-chosen-product-variations-data-into-contact-form-7-enquiry-form/42174658#42174658)
- [Adding custom text labels to the product prices depending on their type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42322098/adding-custom-text-labels-to-the-product-prices-depending-on-their-type)

Answer (score 1):

It should'nt be 'case' it should 'Case', `strstr` is a case sensitive function and as it is boolean the below statment will return false always. Because the values in ur selector is `Case (20 dozens)` not `case (20 dozens)` See the reference below to know more.

Thus change the below line:

```
$has_case = strstr($last_variation_attribute_slug_value, 'case');
```

to:

```
$has_case = strstr($last_variation_attribute_slug_value, 'Case');
```

ref: https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_strstr.asp

Comment: i followed your instructions, but for some products show me "per case" but for that product i dont have variation named "Case"? How is possible to show me "per case" in price when i dont have variation in product ?

For example: http://www.wholesaleunderwear.co/product/rose-ladys-lace-boyshort-4/

But that product dont have "Case" as variation.

http://i.imgur.com/WiuNnyZ.png?1

Comment: Currently it is showing per dozen. right? but u want to show per case?

Comment: @Dora Thats great news. Hope it helped. Do select the appropriate answer as a final answer, so that it can be considered "closed"